# Boost::adaptors::transformed fails to return strings to boost::any_range

Tags: c++, string, boost, range

I've come across a problem with `boost::any_range` losing strings when assigned a return value from `boost::adaptors::transformed`. Here is a sample code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

#include <boost/range/adaptor/transformed.hpp>
#include <boost/range/any_range.hpp>


int main() {
  using my_range = boost::any_range <
    const std::string,
    boost::forward_traversal_tag
  >;

  std::vector<std::string> V = {"foo", "bar"};

  my_range range = V | boost::adaptors::transformed([](auto) { return "Hello World!\n"; });

  for (const auto& v : range) std::cout << v;
}
```

The output is empty for some reason. When I replace strings with some other type like `int` or `double`, everything works as expected. Also, the string `"Hello World"` does get printed out if I do not convert the range returned from the `operator|` (by replacing `my_range range` with `auto range`. What is the reason for such behavior? Is it a bug?

The code was compiled with *MSVC* using *Visual Studio 22*. The version of *Boost* is *1.80*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`any_range` is deducing the reference type of your type-erased range as `const std::string&`, but your lambda returns by value, so you end up getting a dangling reference. You can fix this by making the reference type of the range a value.

Additionally, if the [documentation](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_81_0/libs/range/doc/html/range/reference/adaptors/reference/transformed.html) is correct then `boost::adaptors::transform` is a single pass range, so your tag type is incorrect.

The definition of `my_range` should be:

```
using my_range = boost::any_range <
    const std::string,
    boost::single_pass_traversal_tag,
    const std::string
>;
```

Comment: I guess one forward travesal is enough for a single pass range

Comment: Can I solve this without touching the `my_range` definition? In my real problem the solution you offer is not an option

Comment: In Range-v3 there's something called views::cache1 which caches the current element inside the range, allowing references to be returned. I don't see an equivalent in boost ranges, but maybe you could write one

Comment: Then you could do `V | boost::adaptors::transformed(/*...*/) | my::adaptors::cache1()` or something

Comment: I also didn't quite catch, why does `any_range` take return values by reference and not by value when it knows what the value type is? Besides, afaik temporary values can bind to const references, isn't it the case?

Comment: `any_range` has the `reference_type` template parameter defaulted to `value_type&`. A temporary can bind to a const reference, but lifetime extension doesn't happen in this context.